# Smart Capture and Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloudpage, smart-capture

I have a smart capture form using Cloud Pages and its being used to inject into a journey.

I've set everything up according to this documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_use_a_smart_capture_form_as_a_journey_builder_entry_event.htm&type=5

So the steps that I follow:

1. Create Landing Page with Smart Capture form in Cloud Pages
2. Created the DE and point the Smart Capture form to that
3. Created the Journey Builder using the Cloud Pages entry event

However when I activated the journey the submit button didn't do anything.  Is there anything that I am missing? Where should I start to look to troubleshoot?

Comment: Just for verification, did you create the DE specifically following the steps linked to the above article?  There are many ways to create a DE, but not all will work here.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've had a look further on the whole setup and initially I suspected there was some issue with the code but its apparently not.  I was checking the Inspect console but it's not showing me any errors..  It was the DE configuration.  I had some fields that are non nullable that causing the data injection not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment above.  Need extra attention to details. My DE configuration was created incorrectly by not allowing nullable fields.